# How to save data in mongo collection using spark with mongo-hadoop connector?

Tags: mongodb, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, mongodb-query

I followed mongo-hadoop connector's [documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Spark-Usage).

I am able to transfer data from `inputCol` collection to `outputCol` collection in `testDB` database using:

```
 Configuration mongodbConfig = new Configuration();
 mongodbConfig.set("mongo.job.input.format", "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat");

 mongodbConfig.set("mongo.input.uri", "mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB.inputCol");

 JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkClient.sparkContext);

 JavaPairRDD<Object, BSONObject> documents = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
                mongodbConfig,            // Configuration
                MongoInputFormat.class,   // InputFormat: read from a live cluster.
                Object.class,             // Key class
                BSONObject.class          // Value class
            );


 Configuration outputConfig = new Configuration();
 outputConfig.set("mongo.output.format",
                         "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat");
 outputConfig.set("mongo.output.uri",
                         "mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB.outputCol");

 documents.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
                "file:///this-is-completely-unused",
                Object.class,
                BSONObject.class,
                MongoOutputFormat.class,
                outputConfig
            );
```

I want to save a simple document say

```
{"_id":1, "name":"dev"}
```

in `outputCol` collection  in `testDB` database.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

For using query in Spark MongoDB Hadoop Connector you can use:

```
mongodbConfig.set("mongo.input.query","{'_id':1,'name':'dev'}")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same, just put your `BsonObject` into a `RDD[(Object,BsonObject)]` (that Object can be anything, null should be fine) and save it as you did for *documents*